# Generate routes from controllers' (resources) functions

Tags: laravel

It has been a while I began to think if it's possible to create functions (resources) in Laravel Controller, and then use some kind of command to generate Routes automatically.

For example, with `-r` command we generate basic controller resources. Is there any way to generate routes automatically even with external libraries to look in the route/web file like this;

```
Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index')->name('product.index');
Route::get('/edit', 'ProductController@edit')->name('product.edit');
Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.create');
Route::get('/show', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.show');
Route::get('/store', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
Route::get('/update', 'ProductController@update')->name('product.update');
Route::get('/destroy', 'ProductController@destroy')->name('product.destroy');
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could either create a command that directly appends routes to `routes/web.php`, or adding some database logic inside `routes/web.php` in order to fetch and dynamically generate routes

Comment: I did not understand "adding some database logic inside `routes/web.php`." Please can you help with some example? Thank you

Comment: From your `routes/web.php` file, you could make some sort of loop (e.g. listing all your Controllers, doing a database query for getting a list of routes to generate, ...) which would then create the routes.
Nothing prevents you from calling `Route::get()` from inside a loop!